# $scope undefined within controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm calling JSON data from service and it shows perfectly okay on the View.  However, I'm wondering why $scope.item and $scope.selectedItem are null (or undefined) when I try to log them.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {

    $scope.items = null;
    dataService.getData().then(function (data) {
      $scope.items = data;
    });
    console.log($scope.item);

    $scope.selectedItem = null;
    $scope.passSelection = function (data) {
      $scope.selectedItem = data;
    }
    console.log($scope.selectedItem);
});
```

Comment: it seems like an async issue, your loggers get executed before your service returns the data. If you moved your loggers inside the functions it should log  fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting null when logging because you are assigning the variables asynchronously (within a "then"). I.e. you are starting the requests (getData), logging the value (console.log) and not untill after that does the request finish and the callback (then) fire. So your data is not yet set when you try to log it.

If you log inside your callback instead you would see the correct valyu.

```
$scope.item = null;
dataService.getData().then(function (data) {
  $scope.item = data;
  console.log($scope.item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when you log them it might be `null` and later when you load data they might be getting updated.Try this !

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {

$scope.item = null;
dataService.getData().then(function (data) {
  $scope.item = data;
console.log($scope.item);
});


$scope.selectedItem = null;
$scope.passSelection = function (data) {
  $scope.selectedItem = data;
  console.log($scope.selectedItem);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a promise and your log call executes before your promise completes.

Answer (score 0):

It´s a matter of race conditions. Your console.logs run before you set the actual value to the $scope variables. By moving the console.logs as shown below you should be able to log out the values.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {

  $scope.item = null;
  dataService.getData().then(function (data) {
      $scope.item = data;
      console.log($scope.item); //not undefined
  });
  console.log($scope.item); //undefined
  $scope.selectedItem = null;
  $scope.passSelection = function (data) {
     $scope.selectedItem = data;
     console.log($scope.selectedItem); //not undefined
  }
  console.log($scope.selectedItem); //undefined
});
```